# NullPointerException when using setCurrentMinute(Integer currentMinute) from TimePicker

Tags: android, integer, nullpointerexception, timepicker

```
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker tp, int hour, int min){
        tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(null);
        Integer a = new Integer(5);
        if(a == null){
            Log.d("ff", "integer IS null");
        } else {
            Log.d("ff", "integer is NOT null");
        }
        if(tp == null){
            Log.d("ff", "tp IS null");
        } else {
            Log.d("ff", "tp is NOT null");
        }
        tp.setCurrentMinute(a);
        tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
    }
```

This is my `TimePicker#OnTimeChangedListener`. `tp.setCurrentMinute(a)` causes a `NullPointerException`. I've tried using an int and an Integer - neither works. tp is not null and a isn't either.
Works just fine on emulator, but not on phone running 2.2.

Comment: Stack trace? Also, have you stepped through to the breaking line and evaluated both tp and a to make sure they're really not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> public void **setOnTimeChangedListener** (TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener
>   onTimeChangedListener)
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Set the callback that indicates the time has been adjusted by the
>   user. 
>   **Parameters**
> *onTimeChangedListener* the callback, **should not be
>   null.**

You are setting the listener to null, then when you invoke .setCurrentMinute(a) the TimePicker gives a NullPointerException while trying to notify a null listener